# How to validate "equal slopes" (proportional odds) in ordinal regression

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, ordinal-data, regression-coefficients, validation

I would like to fit an ordinal regression model using proportional odds. I learned to test for "equal slopes" in order to say something about the model's validity.
Therefore, I fit a model *with* equal slopes and I fit a model *without* equal slopes (e.g. with R using the VGAM package).
After that, I do a Chi-square test to compare both results.
If this test *is not* significant, we have equal slopes. If this test *is* significant, we do not.

A colleague states that those tests lack power. With such low power, it could happen that the test is *not* significant (e.g. $p=.2$) while there *are* different slopes.

My questions are:

1. Is there a more powerful way to test for equal slopes?
2. Are there other ways to test the validity of the model?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that not-significant does not mean equal slopes but that there is not enough evidence to reject the hypothesis that the slopes are equal. This makes a difference as an absence of evidence is not the same as evidence of absence. So it is definately possible that the slopes are different but that you do not find such a difference with your test, as your collegue mentioned.

I don't think you should be looking for different tests, but instead use it as statistical tests were intended to be used. In your case you would "hope" for a significant result and than inspect the coefficients and "hopefully" find that they are similar enough to justify a model that sets them as equal. We don't believe that models are true, we just inspect the data and find that the model is a reasonable simplification of reality (simplification is just another word for "wrong in some useful way"). When your test is significant, you know that there is something to inspect. When it is not significant, you will have to find some justification outside your data (e.g. another study using different data)

Comment: Thanks Maarten for this detailed answer. 
The problem I face is: I would like to use a proportional odds model, as it has some advantages (compared to e.g. multiple logistic regression). So in my case, I hope to get *no* significance. But if those Chi-square tests are *not* significant, I still cannot say whether the equal slopes assumption is reasonable or not. Thus, I am searching for an alternative to support my equal slopes assumption. In my case, I cannot use data from different studies, as I am the first one to do research in my specific field...

Comment: I know you want to use the proportional odds model. Now think of what this may mean in terms of testing: No statistcial test can *confirm* a null hypothesis, it can only reject or fail to reject a null hypothesis. If you fail to reject the null, i.e. no significance, you can only say "I don't know", so that is the *worst* possible outcome. The best possible outcome for you is: Find *significant* results, so now you know that there is something to look at, but the coefficients look similar enough to substantively justify the proportional odds model.

Comment: By the way, I hope you are not comparing a proportional odds model with a multinomial logit model. These models are not nested.

Comment: Thx again... and no, I am not comparing PO with MLM..